FlowDocument page width doesn't fill host TabControl content area
I'm having a layout problem trying to host FlowDocument content in a TabControl's content area.
I want the FlowDocumentScrollViewer to render to fit the actual width of the hosting TabControl, but instead it seems to be getting an initial render based on the desired width of the TabControl, and then not responding to the fact that the actual rendered width is different.
Here is simplified XAML which demonstrates the issue:
<Window x:Class="ProblemDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProblemDemo"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
               MinWidth="800" MinHeight="200"
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Background="Bisque">
            Mock Content
        </Label>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" 
               MinWidth="300" MinHeight="500"
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
               VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
               Background="CadetBlue">
            Mock Content
        </Label>
        <TabControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" TabStripPlacement="Bottom">
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <FlowDocumentScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                        <FlowDocumentScrollViewer.Document>
                            <FlowDocument TextAlignment="Left" PageWidth="Auto">
                                <Paragraph FontWeight="Bold">
                                    Sample Header
                                </Paragraph>
                                <Paragraph>
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                </Paragraph>
                                <Paragraph>
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                </Paragraph>
                                <Paragraph>
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                </Paragraph>
                            </FlowDocument>
                        </FlowDocumentScrollViewer.Document>
                    </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <TabItem Header="Item 1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                Content
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>

It looks like this:

If I change the FlowDocument's PageWidth setting from Auto to a fixed value, it does respond to that setting. So it seems that the fundamental problem is that Auto width is not honouring the parent control's actual size. But in my real application, the content in the upper-left (row 0 column 0) and right-hand panes (column 1) are variable size, so I want the FlowDocument to fit its host, rather than setting a fixed PageWidth. How can I make that happen?

Would setting <ColumnDefinition Width="800"/> instead of <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/> be an option? No idea why FlowDocumentScrollViewer behaves that way.

Ideally I'd rather have it be more flexible for handling content of different sizes in R0C0 grid cell, so that changing the layout of the UserControl which I'm hosting in that cell doesn't cause other layout problems. But I see that setting a fixed column width does cause the FlowDocument to render to the correct size, so it's a reasonable workaround for my immediate needs. It's a useful tip, thank you, but I think I can only call it a workaround rather than a true solution.

A FlowDocumentScrollViewer seems to need to be given the width to fully utilize the space. An easy workaround is to bind the actual width of the Label which determines the column width with the width of the TabControl.
<Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
       MinWidth="800"
       x:Name="TopLabel"
       ...
       Background="Bisque">
    Mock Content
</Label>
...
<TabControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" TabStripPlacement="Bottom"
            Width="{Binding ElementName=TopLabel, Path=ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay}">
...
</TabControl>

